# Unable to push my storybooks into chromatic

Tags: github-actions, jobs, storybook, chromatic

I have integrated chromatic into my repository and purpose is to push my storybooks into chromatic.

I have two folder in my repo: 1- backend 2- frontend and I have all storybooks in my frontend folder and my `.github/workflows/chromatic.yml` file looks like below:

```
# .github/workflows/chromatic.yml

# Workflow name
name: 'Chromatic'

# Event for the workflow
on: pull_request

# List of jobs
jobs:
  chromatic-deployment:
    # Operating System
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: frontend
    # Job steps
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn
        #  Runs yarn in ./frontend
        working-directory: frontend
        #  Adds Chromatic as a step in the workflow
      - name: Publish to Chromatic
        uses: chromaui/action@v1
        # Chromatic GitHub Action options
        with:
          #  Chromatic projectToken, refer to the manage page to obtain it.
          workingDir: frontend
          projectToken: ${{ secrets.CHROMATIC_PROJECT_TOKEN }}
```

Is there anything wrong in chromatic.yml file? I have set event on pull request and whenever I create pull request from my branch to another branch(dev) I received notifications that "no job were run" (also attached the screenshot). And when I click "View workflow run" button I got following error:

```
Error: .github#L1
The job was not started because recent account payments have failed or your spending limit needs to be increased. Please check the 'Billing & plans' section in your settings.
```

(I have researched this error and also tried different ways as suggested but same issue I am getting).

[image]

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.